# How to add a key,value pair to JObject using json4s in Scala?

Tags: scala, json4s

I parse json using **json4s** library: [GitHub json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s)

I have a empty JObject:

```
val json = JObject()
```

how to add key,value pair to JObject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
json ~ ("foo" -> "bar")
```

or

```
json merge JObject("foo" -> JString("bar"))
```

Comment: Thank you! But it looks very inconvenient.

Comment: Thank you! It's very useful! DSL is better. And I have another question: there is a JObject `val json = parse("""{"a":"b"}""")` , I get value by `compact(json \ "a")`, Is there another way to get value from JObject?

Comment: @Guo (json \ "a") returns you JString("b"). You could match this `JValue` as `(json \ "a") match {case JString(s) => s; case ... => ...}`. But better read case class from json, process it and write in the end. Then you will interact with jsons only inside reading/error handling layer. https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-classes-defined-in-traits-or-classes